# How do I use a different version of openssl?

Tags: path, gui, openssl

I have downloaded, compiled, and tested, openssl 1.0.2d.  I can use it preferentially in my shell by editing .bash_profile and placing the openssl_x84_64 at the beginning of PATH.  I would like to know how to get programs such as web browsers, etc., to use this version.  I suspect that they do not, since they run directly from the GUI.

Comment: Using OS X El Capitan

Comment: It's *very* unlikely programs use the `openssl` *executable*; some *might* use the openssl *libraries* `libssl*` and `libcrypto*`, but I'd expect (most?) things on MacOSX (and certainly Safari) to use Apple's Secure Transport instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a symlink to your version.

e.g. In your case openssl should be located in /usr/bin

Do something like:
`#mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl_OLD` (To make sure you can revert if needed)
Then link your compiled version location:
`#ln -s /path/to/your/openssl-1.0.2d/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl`